# What happened to the blender UI

Tags: interface

I have found this link to a blender ui proposal:http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UWacQrEcMHk

The link is from 2013, and it seems very convincing. I don't what happened to it, and now in 2015, I can't find any links yo what happened next.
What happened to this proposal? Are there plans to apply such UI?

Comment: That was a proposal/case_study by Andrew Price, in no way not a road map by the developers. Listen to this blender's guru's own podcast on the issue http://www.blenderguru.com/podcasts/podcast-interface-feuds/

Comment: @cegaton I understand it was just a proposal. But I wanted to know if there is a will to implement such feature or was it just declined. I couldn't find the result anywhere on the web.

Comment: On the blendr foundation's response to the proposal: http://www.cgchannel.com/2013/10/the-blender-foundation-responds-to-ui-criticisms/

Comment: http://code.blender.org/index.php/2013/10/redefining-blender/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a question about blender but about a feature request.

Comment: @cegaton I understand, but why did you answer it from the first place.

Comment: @Mnmd Ton's statement was a bit too long to put as a comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's worth reproducing Ton's [statement on this issue](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2013/10/redefining-blender/) here:

> A lot of (really great) UI design proposals that went on the past week give quite a false impression that it’s either feasible to just replace the UI, or that its possible to pay for it – even when it takes a dozen people a year to work on.
>
> The misconception here is that the “UI” is some kind of separated entity of a program, which can just be peeled off and replaced with another interface. However, a really good UI (and certainly Blender’s) is not just an abstract independent layer, it’s the reflection (and sometimes even the core) of the program’s design.
>
> You can easily state that a significant part of the Blender code (more than a quarter) is “the interface”. You cannot code any tool without understanding “the UI”. You cannot work on compositing or rendering without keeping track of it. A particle system is “UI”. How animation systems relate is “UI”. How files read and write is “UI”. The way how undo works is even “UI”.
>
> So – replacing a UI can be as impossible as trying to replace the script in a film. Let’s not go that way now. A full rewrite of Blender might happen once, but I think we have enough quality code design in Blender still – and a whole lot of open todo topics – to fill at least several years of coding time with.